# Duplicate FragmentContainerView in Android navigation components

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am creating a single activity application using jetpack navigation. Everything is working as expected. I have a requirement to make some fragments full screen.

Here is my layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
    tools:context=".features.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_header"
        app:itemShapeInsetStart="0dp" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see I have used the `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute in `FragmentContainerView`.
But this is not working as expected and after inspecting the layout using **Layout Inspector** I am seeing duplicate `FragmentContainerView` in the view hierarchy.

Here is a screen shot of the view hierarchy.
[image]

The problem this creates is that the first `FragmentContainerView` has the `fitsSystemWindows` attribute set to true but the second `FragmentContainerView` doesn't have that attribute set. I also tried the [Advanced Navigation Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) and inspected the view and it also has the duplicate `FragmentContainerView`.

Can anyone please explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I faced the same issue and don't have a cue about the cause of it at all. It seems strange that this question has not any interaction. Do you find new things about it?